# How can I get the highlighted text from PSPDFKit?

Tags: annotations, highlight, pspdfkit

I am using PSPDFKit to let users highlight text in a document. Is there anyway to get the actual text that was highlighted? So in the following example, I would like to get the text "the good and bad" when the user highlights it.

[image]

Looking at the PSAnnotations, I've tried the value and contents properties but neither gives me what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the CEO of PSPDFKit GmbH.

All you need to do is get the [`PSPDFHighlightAnnotation`](http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFHighlightAnnotation.html) (e.g. via [`annotationsForPage:type:`](http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFDocument.html#//api/name/annotationsForPage%3atype%3a) in [`PSPDFDocument`](http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFDocument.html) and then call [`highlightedString`](http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFAbstractTextOverlayAnnotation.html#//api/name/highlightedString) on it.

Please be aware that this is only an approximation. We only know the position of each individual glyph on the page, and from that, PSPDFKit tries to reconstruct words, lines and text boxes. So [`highlightedString`](http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFAbstractTextOverlayAnnotation.html#//api/name/highlightedString) might not always return 100% what you'd expect, especially if the PDF is not well-designed. But in general, it's quite good.