# In PSPDFKit how do I get highlighted text?

Tags: javascript, annotations, highlight, pspdfkit

There is an older response to this question in [How can I get the highlighted text from PSPDFKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314645/how-can-i-get-the-highlighted-text-from-pspdfkit) but all the links are dead and the solution may have been refactored drastically since 2014.

All I get from the response from [`instance.exportInstantJSON()`](https://pspdfkit.com/api/web/PSPDFKit.Instance.html#exportInstantJSON) is the coordinates of a rectange annotation of my highlighted annotation, is there any way to resolve these coordinates and get the text being highlighted?

[image: partial console dump]

Using PSPDFKit version 2022.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug a bit deeper in the API documentation and found there is a [`instance.getMarkupAnnotationText`](https://pspdfkit.com/api/web/PSPDFKit.Instance.html#getMarkupAnnotationText) method which does the job.

```
const annotations = await instance.getAnnotations(0);
const markupAnnotations = annotations.filter(
  annotation => annotation instanceof PSPDFKit.Annotations.MarkupAnnotation
);
const text = await Promise.all(
  markupAnnotations.map(instance.getMarkupAnnotationText)
);
console.log(text);
```